# Why is the word const not in front of these arrow functions when module.exports is used?

Tags: javascript

I have this code from a tutorial:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/auth.config');
const db = require('../db');
const User = db.user;
const Role = db.role;

verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (!token) {
        return fail(res, {message: 'No token provided'});
    }

    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (error, decoded) => {
        if (error) {
          return fail(res, {message: 'Unauthorized'});
        }
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next();
    });

};

isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.userId).exec()
    .then((user) => {
       // What does this mean?
       return Role.find({_id: {$in: user.roles}});
     })
     .then(() => {
       if (!roles.includes('admin')) {
           return fail(res, {message: 'Require admin role'});
       }
       next();
     })
     .catch(() => fail(res, {message: 'Database internal error occured.'}));
};

isModerator = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.userId).exec()
    .then(() => {
        return Role.find({_id: {$in: user.roles}});
     })
     .then(() => {
         if (!roles.includes('moderator')) {
             return fail(res, {message: 'Require moderator role'});
          }
          next();
     })
     .catch(() => fail(res, {message: 'Database internal error occured.'}));
};

module.exports = {
    verifyToken,
    isAdmin,
    isModerator
};
```

Why is the word `const` not in front of the arrow function definitions? For example shouldn't it be `const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {....`, is this related to the `module.exports` at the bottom of the file?

Comment: I'd say they *should* be properly declared. Right now they are implicit globals. Only for the module but there is no real benefit to that either way. Seems like sloppy coding rather than a deliberate choice.

Comment: There should indeed be a `const`. No good reason why there isn't.

Comment: They could be `let`, sometimes it is useful to allow a function to be replaced.

Comment: @QuentinUK doesn't really matter in this case. And overall, I don't see a good reason to have `let` here - this is a very simple module. If you need to change the variable, you most likely just need a single assignment anyway. The exported values don't care whether they've been declared with `const` or `let` or are an implicit global.